# Automatically adjust the "RC" in an English formula based on the user's client language

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-4.0

So I was surprisingly getting error reports from many users for a new tool I made. Those users all have the German version of Excel installed. After a quick glance, I figured out the problem:

I used this formula as a named function to get the color of the adjacent cell (don't ask me why that's important, but things depend on the result):

```
=GET.CELL(63;OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC";FALSE);0;1))
```

Now in the German version, the "RC" remains, but would have to change to "ZS" for the formula to not throw a reference error.

It's written the way it is to reference the cell the function is in.

Is it possible to rewrite this formula in a way that does not "hard code" the "RC" so it can change depending on the localization of the user (Chinese and Czech would be relevant too)? Or is it possible to replace the named formula with a bit of VBA code that can check for the language version of the user?

If I can't adjust this bit of the tool I'll have to go with a less attractive workaround (Have multiple Y/N checks instead of assigning colors).

Comment: What is this "tool" you're talking about? A vba program? Please elaborate, I don't understand what you're working with. You could probably list countries and ask the user to select. Then you can use if then else or vba to change that.

Comment: Well, I didn't feel it was relevant in the slightest, but it's a tool that uses a lot of vba code and some formulas to do something confidential. I'm just wondering if it's possible to adjust the formula or replace it with some vba function to auto adjust the "RC" part to different language settings, as formulas usually do when you don't put stuff in quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not actually answer my question, but it does solve my problem. Turns out that entering

```
=GET.CELL(63;Sheet!B1)
```

In the name manager while having A1 selected delivers exactly the same result as

```
=GET.CELL(63;OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC";FALSE);0;1))
```

Being that it gets the cell color number from the cell one to the right, no matter where you then insert this function.

Comment: Well, as long as you're on Sheet1, anyway. ;) If you're using VBA anyway, why don't you use a UDF for this?

Comment: I only need it on that sheet and it's solved my problem. The only vba solution I know of would require me to add ifs for every single install language.

Answer (score -1):

You can then find the user's LCID using a vba code such as

```
dim lcode as long
lcode = Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
```

You can then us a simple if then else and connect the LCID to appropriate strings using ([this](http://www.orbus.be/bosanski_jezik/language_codes.htm)). Example:

```
If lcode = "0407" Then
Cells(5, 5).Formula = "=GET.CELL(63;OFFSET(INDIRECT(""ZS"";FALSE);0;1))"
ElseIf lcode = "1033" Then
Cells(5, 5).Formula = "=GET.CELL(63;OFFSET(INDIRECT(""RC"";FALSE);0;1))"
End If
```

Alternatively, you can also define a string i and based on the LCID you can attach i the appropriate value based on the result and use:

```
Cells(5, 5).Formula = "=GET.CELL(63;OFFSET(INDIRECT(" & i & ";FALSE);0;1))"
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work great if it was all in vba, but I don't think this works as a named function inside a regular formula in the worksheet. Also because the get.cell formula resolves as a NAME error if typed directly into a cell, it only works as a name (more specifically as an x4 macro).

Comment: I didn't notice that at all as I don't use this very often. If you want to just match the color of a cell to another adjacent cell you could just use the vba formula like: Cells.Range("B4").Interior.Color = Cells.Range("A4").Interior.Color

Answer (score -1):

This is easily solved with a UDF

Option 1: pass the cell you want the color of as a parameter (this cell can be anywhere, not limited to the next cell to the right)

```
Function GetColor(r As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    GetColor = r.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Option 2: get the color of the next cell to the right of the cell containing the formula

```
Function GetColorNextCell() As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    GetColorNextCell = Application.ThisCell.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

That said, using format as data is a *bad* idea.  Both these formula (and your named range version) won't update when you just change the color of a cell.  They all required you to force a recalc to update (changing format does *not* trigger a recalc).

I've made them Volitile so they at least update on *all* recalcs, but even then they won't update if you *just* change the color.

You are representing *something* with that color.  I'd suggest you change that to use a specific value in the cell to represent whatever that is.  You can always use Conditional Formatting to also color the cell based on that value.